# contact of hypersurface and curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, submanifold

Could anyone explain the following fact in detail?

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is smooth and $\nabla f\neq 0$ on the level set $M = \{f=0\}$, so that $M$ is a smooth hypersurface. A smooth regular curve $\phi:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ has m-order contact with the hypersurface $M$ at $\phi(0) \iff (f\circ \phi)^{(i)}(0) = 0, 0\leq i \leq m$.

Currently, I am a little confused about how to choose the curve $\psi$ in M s.t.
$$\phi^{(i)}(0) = \psi^{(i)}(0), 0\leq i\leq m$$ in $\impliedby$ case.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... Isn't the equivalence just the definition of an $m$-order contact? Or what alternate definition do you have?

Comment: The definition I am using is that the hypersurface  and curve  have m-order contact at a point  if there exists a curve ⊂ passing through p such that the two curves  and  have m-order contact at p. I cannot simply choose  itself in the backward case since  is not necessary in the hypersurface. @mathcounterexamples.net